# Defining C# enums with descriptions

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums

What would the folowing VB.NET enum definition look like in C#?

```
Public Enum SomeEnum As Integer
    <Description("Name One")> NameOne = 1
End Enum
```

Comment: Man are we sad or what, 6 answers within a minute.

Comment: It almost seems like the "6 news answers have been posted for this question" feature on is broken ;)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Clearly, there is one feature missing in StackOverflow comments - the "also post to twitter" checkbox. :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public enum SomeEnum: int
{
    [Description("Name One")]
    NameOne = 1,
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public enum SomeEnum : int
{
    [Description("Name One")] NameOne = 1
}
```

Comment: The `: int` part can be left out, as that would be the default.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
enum SomeEnum
{
    [Description("Name One")] NameOne = 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public enum SomeEnum : int
{
[Description("Name One")]
NameOne = 1
}
```

Comment: (although the :int isn't actually necessary)

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum SomeEnum 
{
[Description("Name One")]
NameOne = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:-

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
   [Description("Name One")]
   NameOne = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum SomeEnum : int 
{ 
    [Description("Name One")] NameOne = 1 
}
```